# DVD-RW Drive not recognizing a DVD+R disc

Tags: windows-vista, dvd, burning, compact-disc, optical-drive

I am having trouble burning DVD+R disc's.  My OS is vista and i have used this burner and these same discs in the past.  I haven't had the need to do so in months and now that i come back to create some backups my DVD/RW drive doesn't recognize a brand new DVD+R disc.  These disc are the same ones i have used in the past(Same Pack even).  Anyone have any idea what this might be.  Maybe a vista upgrade or something that i downloaded in the last few months that could have thrown something off?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as per @Havenard's question - do you mean you have a DVD-RW drive? If so, it shouldn't burn DVD+R's at all. I'm guessing you meant DVD RW, but could you clarify?

Answer (score 4):

Probably just a dirty or dying DVD drive: it's the transport/laser/firmware that reads the disk.

My old DVD drive does not read some DVD writable disks, whether I used XP, XP x64 or now Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

DVD-R and DVD+R are different medias, never heard of a DVD-RW recorder working with DVD+R medias... are you sure it ever happened?